# Entering fullscreen from within <iframe> in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fullscreen

I want my iframe to go fullscreen from an HTML5 Fullscreen event trigger within the iFrame itself. Is this possible?

Comment: @robertc - I have. Doesn't work. Perhaps someone knows a workaround?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course you can! Youtube HTML5 player does!

You can use this javascript library http://brad.is/coding/BigScreen/ and remember to add the tag `AllowFullScreen` to your iframe.